# Ajax with Laravel Form Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

```
{!! Form::select('jobsList[]', $list_of_jobs, null, ['id' => 'job', 'class' => 'form-control' 'multiple', 'style' => 'width: 60%; margin-top: 10px;', 'disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
```

I have this form and I am trying to load $list_of_jobs asynchronously compared to what I am doing. I am kind of confused with the way LaravelCollective Form works. Can anyone point out how I would pass that? I already have ajax call that goes and grabs the $list_of_jobs from the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//...
{!! Form::select('jobsList[]', [], null, ['id' => 'job', 'class' => 'form-control' 'multiple', 'style' => 'width: 60%; margin-top: 10px;', 'disabled'=>'disabled']) !!}
..//
```

> Populating your select box using JQUERY, AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

            //Make an Ajax request to a Laravel route
            //This will return the data that we can add to our Select element.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'YOUR URL GOES HERE',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data){

                    //Log the data to the console so that
                    //you can get a better view of what the script is returning.
                    console.log(data);

                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        //Use the Option() constructor to create a new HTMLOptionElement.
                        var option = new Option(key, value);
                        //Convert the HTMLOptionElement into a JQuery object that can be used with the append method.
                        $(option).html(value);
                        //Append the option to our Select element.
                        $("#job").append(option);
                    });

                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

> `data` must be an array of objects `[{}, {}, {}]`

```
[
  {'key' : 'foo', 'value' => 'bar'}, 
  {'key' : 'kosksi', 'value' => 'makrouna'}, 
  {'key' : 'lablebi', 'value' => 'kafteji'}
]
```

## Update

If you want to set selected `option(s)` when Populating your select box :
You need to return an extra attribute `selected : true|false` in each object of data collection

```
[
  {'key' : 'foo', 'value' : 'bar', 'selected' : false}, 
  {'key' : 'kosksi', 'value' : 'makrouna', 'selected' : false}, 
  {'key' : 'lablebi', 'value' : 'kafteji', 'selected' : true}
]
```

Then in `success()` ajax function callback

```
//...
$.each(data, function(key, elem){
  //Use the Option() constructor to create a new HTMLOptionElement.            
  var option = new Option(elem.value, elem.key, false, elem.selected);
  //Convert the HTMLOptionElement into a JQuery object that can be used with the append method.
  $(option).html(elem.value);
  //Append the option to our Select element.
  $("#job").append(option);
});
//...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after i fixed my backend json data it worked well. Tho I have another question $list_of_jobs used to show the variables that was selected and saved before, but now it doesn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: And the 'selected' should come from the controller?

Comment: Yes, from the controller